# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'displayTagInfo' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<tagname>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, html, django

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path("<str:tagname>", views.displayTagInformation, name='displayTagInfo'),
   # path('displayTagInformation',views.displayTagInformation)
]
```

In this urls tagname is string which I got from  list data.

**home.html**

```
<form action="dispalyTagName" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h3 align="center">Tags</h3>
                        <h6>{{ userName }}                      
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% for tagname in tagNameList %}
                            <a href="{{tagname}}" title="Created by: {{ userName }}">{{ tagname }} ,</a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </form>

                    </form>
```

Here I am trying to fetch all list in for loop as link because I want to pass that link again to py file.

**views.py**

```
def displayTagInformation(request, tagname):
    print("selected tag name : ", tagname)
    databaseTags = TagsInformation.objects.filter(tagName = tagname).values()

    global tagDesc
    addedTagdata= list(databaseTags)
    print(addedTagdata)
    print(type(addedTagdata))
    for tagDescription in addedTagdata:
       tagDesc=tagDescription.get("tagDescription")


    return render(request, "questionnaireApp/TagTable.html", {'addedTagdata': addedTagdata, 'selectedTagName':tagname,'tagDesc':tagDesc})
```

In view function I fetched data from sqlite database and I got list  addedTagdata. I fetched some data with the help of this list. 
I got above exception.

Comment: There error is not in *this* view. It is in a template that aims to generate a link *to* that view.

Comment: But that being said, please do *not* use `.values()` or `global` in your views. Especially `global` is a severe anti-pattern, since it makes your view more stateful.

Comment: try this: <a href="{% url 'displayTagInfo' tagname=tagname %}" title="Created by: {{ userName }}">. 2) why are you using form if there is no fields in form.